Integrating Custom Post Types with REST API Endpoints in WordPress 5.9
I'm working with a custom WordPress site and attempting to extend the REST API to include custom post types with associated custom fields. I'm using WordPress 5.9 and have followed the documentation to register a custom post type with 'show_in_rest' => true.
Here's the code snippet from my theme's functions.php:
function create_movie_post_type() {
  register_post_type('movie',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Movies'),
        'singular_name' => __('Movie')
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'rest_base' => 'movies',
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields')
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'create_movie_post_type');

Custom fields have been added with ACF, and I can see the post type in the WP admin and via direct REST API access at site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/movies.
However, the custom fields I've added aren't showing up in the REST API response. Is there an additional step to include ACF fields in the REST API for a custom post type?
I haven't found any recent resources post-WordPress 5.8 addressing this, especially with the Gutenberg editor in play. Any insights or links to up-to-date guides would be appreciated.

Are you using ACF or ACF Pro?

I'm using ACF PRO for this project

Do you have enabled "Show in REST API" at the field group level? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/

"Yes, that was the issue. I've checked the ACF field group settings and ensured 'Show in REST API' is enabled, and now the custom fields are appearing as expected in the REST API responses. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!"
